# CSS background and background-image only shows up on chrome desktop broswer

Tags: html, css

The image of a background: or background-image: not showing up on website, img src not showing up either.

However, all pictures show up fine only on chrome desktop broswer, but they don’t show up on chrome mobile broswer. Some of the browsers I’ve tested and don’t show the images on my website are: chrome mobile, safari mobile, IE desktop, Microsoft edge desktop.

The entire html css code can be found at the website, is it allowed to include the link in my post?
styles.css

```
.wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-image: url('./imgSrc/chessbk.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    /*        background-attachment: fixed;*/
    /*    -o-background-size: cover;*/
    /*-moz-background-size: cover;*/
    /*-webkit-background-size: cover;*/
}

/* Main page style */
.wrapper .main {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}


.main {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(172, 207, 229, 1), rgba(172, 207, 229, .1));
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
} /*----end main page styles---*/

/* Main page header style */
.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header .headerIMG {
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.siteTitle {
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    position: relative;
    color: floralwhite;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
} /*-----end header styles----*/

/* Navigation styles */
#access {
    background: url('./imgSrc/access_bg.png');
    /*
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    */
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Case of using background: HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="headerIMG" style="background: url(imgSrc/planet.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;">
                </div>

                <div class="siteTitle">
                    <h1> Rocky Mountain Chess Rating System</h1>
                    <h2> Idaho Chess Association Database</h2>
                </div>
```

Further down in the html file above:

```
 <div class="main">
                <div class="icaImg">
                    <a href="https://www.idahochessassociation.com/"> <img src="imgSrc/icaLogo.png"> </a>
                </div>
                <div id="contentGameEnter">
                    <div class="enterGame">
```

Just tested it, this is an update edit, images appear on safari desktop and Firefox desktop. So the browsers which don’t work are mobile browsers and IE desktop, Microsoft edge desktop

Comment: Pleas show us your code.

Comment: @Markus Can I post links to website where code is?

Comment: It’s recommended to extract the part which is relevant for your questions from the whole code and add it to this post.

Comment: Ok on it please stop downvoting adding code now

Comment: Code up. I can add any other code that may be important to figuring out this problem, but I am pretty sure I included the necessary code.

Comment: I have been researching non-stop nothing I find will help, so I hope you guys can help. Do you want me to post the url to website or maybe all of the code? Seems like no one has any advice yet.

Comment: Will put this in Orignial post however, just tested it pictures show up in safari desktop and Firefox desktop

Comment: Well, for one thing, `background: url()` should have quotes around the actual URL, like `background: url('mywebsite.com/image.jpg')`.

Comment: Everybody, any idea why when I got https my images are now showing up on the browsers they weren’t?? Meaning problem fixed but why and how, also marsandback still don’t have quotes around it, they are not needed...and it still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get https, I used letsencrypt to get free sll certificate, it solves the problem. In other words, getting https has now allowed the images to show up on chrome mobile, safari mobile, (chrome desktop, but they already showed here), IE desktop. Overall, get https it solved this problem for me.